# No USBs detected on Windows 10 guest with virtualbox (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1)?

Tags: 20.04, usb, virtualbox

ENVIRONMENT:
host - **Ubuntu 20.04.1**
guest - **Windows 10**
virtualbox  - **6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1**
virtualbox extensions pack - **6.1.10-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1**

I installed extensions pack (6.1.10-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) and guest additions(though this is not required for getting USB's working in guests).

Shared folders, shared clipboard, webcam, audio (in and out) are working fine.

But USBs are not getting detected by VirtualBox.
(At the time of below screenshot I have a USB pendrive plugged in to the system.)

[image: Devices > USB context menu shows "No USB Devices Connected]

Current USB settings use USB 2.0 -  but I tried 3.0 too and no luck.

Every USB Port on my system is USB 3.1 Gen 1 port (data transfer speeds up to 5 Gbps)

[image: USB settings - USB 2.0]

Any hints on how to fix this? Previous posts may not help much as I am thinking environment makes bit of difference. (I myself had USBs working across guests on earlier setups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the current user to vboxusers group fixed the problem. The USB devices are now showing up on the Windows 10 VM.

```
sudo gpasswd -a yourusername vboxusers
```

Reference - [How to Access USB from VirtualBox Guest OS](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/access-usb-from-virtualbox-guest-os)